# Get Rows based on distinct values from Column 1, while keep as many distinct values from column 2 as possible

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matched dataset of treated and control columns. My problem is to pick a control for each treated observation, basically a one-to-one match with replacement, except that I'd like to keep as many unique controls as possible, i.e., I'd like to exploit full info in the control group and don't want to give too much weight to a single control observation.

For a specific example, after the match, I have the dataframe below with duplicated values in both treated and control columns:

```
>>>df
treated control
A    a
A    b
B    a
B    b
C    a
C    b
D    a
D    d
```

I would like to get the rows based on unique values in treated, while **at the same time keep as many unique values** from controls as possible. That is, I'd like to get either

```
>>>df
treated control
A    a
B    b
C    a
D    d
```

or

```
>>>df
treated control
A    b
B    a
C    a
D    d
```

or any output that keeps all unique values of the control column in this example (and maintain the correct pairs). That is, I don't want to get, for example

```
>>>df
treated control
A    a
B    a
C    a
D    a
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df=df.apply(pd.unique)`?

Comment: The question for me is, what happens if there are mismatched lengths of values in col1 and col2? Like `'A' 'B' 'C'` in col1 and just `'a' 'b'` in col2.

Comment: @AnuragDabas, thanks, it seems to work for "square" dataframes, otherwise it throws an error "arrays must all be same length". I am not sure how pd.unique works in df.apply.

Comment: @HenryEcker, please see my edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html#pandas-unique) + [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series) + [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html#pandas-dataframe-ffill):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'C'},
    'col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'a', 5: 'b'}
})

new_df = (
    df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.unique(x)))
        .ffill()  # fill NaNs with any value
)

print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
  col1 col2
0    A    a
1    B    b
2    C    b
```

Comment: Thanks, Henry. The problem with the answer is that I still need the original paired values between col1 and col2, which can be lost in the transformation. I made a bit edits to the question to clarify its application.